# "be excited about" and "be looking forward to"

Tags: word-choice, difference

I'm not sure about what I can say when you are looking forward to doing something.

I wonder if I can say

> I'm looking forward to eating curry.

in such a situation: A boy is at an Indian restaurant and waiting for the dish.
He will get the curry very soon. Is he "looking forward"?

I think I should use "excited" instead since from the phrase "look forward" I imagine a picture where a person is looking toward the far destination.

> I'm excited about eating curry.

Is it right?

Comment: 'Looking forward' can be about something at any time in the future, whether it is expected very soon or not.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oh, I see! thank you so much!!  Then, how about "be excited about"? Can it also be about something at any time in the future?

Comment: 'Looking forward to' and 'being excited about' something do not have to mean exactly the same thing. I can be excited about my trip to China next year, or I might just be looking forward to it, and only get excited the day or week before. Have you looked in a dictionary for these terms?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you for your answer!  I think I know what "be excited" means in sentences like "I was excited to hear the news", but I couldn't find "be excited about something" in my dictionary.  When I met this expression, I thought It might be able to be used when you are looking forward to something.  I don't really know what it means.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Maybe I should examine the word "about" in that sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "I'm looking forward to" can only refer to events in the future, but any time in the near or far future is okay.  It means that you anticipate with pleasure that the event will be a positive one for you in some way.

The expression "I'm excited about" implies a reference to something you have in your mind in the present.  The thing causing excitement is not really restricted to a particular time present or future, but implies something existing in the present or near future, since "excitement is an emotion limited in time."  It refers to an agitated emotional state that is not normal for you and is overwhelmingly used to describe a positive feeling, although it is not exclusively used in that way.  It expresses a stronger emotion than "looking forward to."

The expression "I'm excited to" refers to the same emotional state as "excited about" but, like the first, expression can only apply to a future event because of the shared preposition "to."